# Working out the constants and probabilities of Stockmeyer's approximate counting algorithm

Tags: approximation-algorithms, counting-complexity, randomized-algorithms

Stockmeyer's [1983 result](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/800061.808740) on approximate counting using a randomness states that if we have some SAT instance $x$ with $C(x)$ satisfying assignments, then we can find the minimum set of $m$ hash functions such that applying the hash functions to the set of satisfying assignments yields different outputs for each assignment and so:

$$2^{m-c-1} \leq  C(x) \leq m 2^m,$$
where $c$ is a constant that Stockmeyer mentions is due to [Sipser](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/800061.808762). This result is part of Theorem 3.1, under Equation (4). This inequality means we can approximate $C(x)$ up to a factor of $(m2^m) / 2^{m-c-1} = m2^{c+1}$.

I have two related questions:

First, how can we calculate this constant $c$? I know the algorithm allows amplification of its results so in some sense this $c$ is irrelevant, but suppose I don't do any amplification. What kind of bound do we get? I've looked at Sipser's paper, and this is unclear to me. If I look at Theorem 7.14 of [this book](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/PDF/rnd.pdf) it seems like we can use these ideas to get to a factor of $2^4 = 16$.

Second, Stockmeyer's algorithm is probabilistic in that it relies on sampling random hash functions. Therefore, the algorithm should only succeed with some probability. What is that probability?

Comment: idgi, why can't you just calculate it?

Comment: It’s not clear to me how Sipser finds this constant $c$, nor how we can find the probability of success in the algorithm.

Comment: what exactly is unclear (when you go through the proof to figure out $c$)?

Comment: In Sipser's paper, I don't see where $c$ even comes from. I imagine it's after Theorem 2, but I can't seem to find mention of it (I could be missing something simple!).